# How can I reduce the initial load of page?

Tags: 7, performance

I've been monitoring the speed of my site load on Drupal 7 and I would like to increase its initial loading speed. Currently it takes 6 seconds just to get data from the server. What is the first page called? In total it takes about 10 seconds for my site to load.

What methods are there to reducing this initial startup load time? I've tried boost, but I can't use it as it renders all my webforms useless. I've already used the lazyloader module for images and enabled gzip aswell.

[image]

Comment: have you tried any caching methods?

Comment: I'm able to reduce alot of the images and video content to load via ajax after the page loads fully. But I'm not sure how to further improve the initial page load when the browser first fetches the page. I'm not sure why it takes 6 seconds for the server to spit out the page. How do I even debug something like that? Which logs should I be looking? Is it due to sql queries being run on the back end ?

Comment: This is your time to first byte (TTFB), the page has not even requested the css, javascript and images yet. You need to look into server solutions to cache SQL and / or compiled PHP. Have a look at [memcached](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) and compile PHP with Opcache (opcode cache) enabled.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much you can do with the browser debugging tools in this case. You need to debug this on the server:

https://docs.acquia.com/articles/using-xhprof-evaluate-code-performance